# Future society where tipping is mandatory

Tags: story-identification

I read this in an unremembered anthology in the UK, between the late 1970s and early 1980s.

A future society set in the US, it begins with a typical day in main characters life, he goes to leave his apartment and casually drops a few cents in the tip box on his door lock, a little robot voice says "thank you" as he walks away.
All that day he automatically drops a few cents into tip boxes everywhere he goes, grocery store, walking through his office etc. People all around do the same routinely.

One day he goes to leave and finds he forgot to pick up a roll of change from the bank so his pockets are empty.
He asks the door to open and it refuses, he states he'll double the usual tip when he gets home, he asks why it expects a tip every time, surely it's a voluntary thing.

The auto door explains that it's no longer a voluntary thing, it became mandatory a few years ago and he must pay to use the door.

The man sighs and gets a screwdriver and begins removing the hinges as the robot box screeches for help down the block corridor.

Comment: [Dupe here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/) - not sure about which direction to VTC though

Comment: It's not really a dupe @fez, it's a different question that happens to have the same answer.  The details wanting to be identified are entirely different.

Comment: @iandotkelly I believe the policy for ID questions is that two questions are duplicates if they're about the same work, regardless of how many details match between the two questions themselves.

Comment: Hmm.... if the purpose of such questions is that they are re-used by others, mixing up the vastly different details seems not to be the best idea.  You could (or should?) merge the questions, but it could become unwieldy.  Not the place to debate policy though.

Comment: The fact that we can't really tell what direction to VTC is because they are essentially completely different fully formed and easily answerable questions about the same novel.

Comment: @iandotkelly - according to [our site policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/) story-id questions are dupes if they have the same answer. Historically the older question is chosen as the main dupe target, but newer questions have been chosen because there're more details in the question or the answer, and sometimes it's up to how many votes there are. Most of the time some details are shared so it's quite easy to tell, here it's a bit difficult

Comment: @fez.  Again, I don't really feel I'm enough in this community to contest this, and this isn't the right place - but the policy is far from clear to me, even reading through some meta content.  The meta question you post here is asking about the specifics where there is no acceptance, and states without much evidence that it is 'generally agreed' we should VTC one of the questions, linking to a very inconclusive meta question where the highest voted thing is the question which suggests having a 'light touch' since it is hard to have specific rules around this.

Comment: @iandotkelly - that might not have been the best meta post to link, just the first I could find. There's a long history when it comes to story id questions and duplicate closures. Perhaps it's time for a new discussion in meta regarding this point

Comment: @iandotkelly - I've given up on this battle. According to SF&F dup rules, *What is 6 x 7* would be identified as the same question as *What is the Meaning of Life*. :(

Comment: Don't worry, this can't be closed. Another question was closed once so it would be a duplicate closing.

Comment: @HannoverFist I wouldn’t say it’s that strict at all. However in this case the answers both identify the same piece of work. So one must be a duplicate of the other

Comment: If I'd knew it would cause such a debate I'd never have asked the question!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[Ubik](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?948)*, the novel by P.K. Dick.

Near the start of the novel, the lead charcter, Joe Chip, has run out of change, and is unable to have his aprtment cleaned, or prepare coffee, or even to open his aprtment's front door:

> The door refused to open. It said, ‘Five cents, please."
>
> He searched his pockets. No more coins; nothing. ‘I'll pay you
> tomorrow,’ he told the door. Again he tried the knob. Again it
> remained locked tight. “What I pay you,’ he informed it, ‘is in the
> nature of a gratuity; I don’t have to pay you.’
>
> ‘I think otherwise,’ the door said. ‘Look in the purchase contract you
> signed when you bought this conapt.’

In desperation, Chip starts removing the hinges from the door in order to escape:

> From the drawer beside the sink Joe Chip got a stainless steel knife;
> with it he began systematically to unscrew the bolt assembly of his
> apt’s money-gulping door.
>
> "I'll sue you,” the door said as the first screw fell out.
>
> Joe Chip said, ‘I’ve never been sued by a door. But I guess I can live
> through it.’

Finally, however, he is released when a visitor arrives, and puts a nickel in the door in order to enter.